# SQL where clause selecting specific data

Tags: sql, where-clause

In Microsoft SQL, I am trying to select a specific result from a table when available. Otherwise, other data should be retrieved.

Giving the scenario tableA contains various fruits. I want to collect apples that are red otherwise, any other colors except for red should be retrieved.

I am not sure which approach to go with, having a Case Statement  or using EXISTS in the where clause. I tried both method but without the desired outcome.

```
select * 
from tableA 
where fruit = 'apple' 
and color = case when color = 'red' then 
                      'red' 
                 else color <> 'red' 
            end
```

Based on some of the initial comments, elaborating on the existing question,

if putting this into If else logic, it would be

If red apples are available, retrieve red apples else retrieve any other colors except for red.

Comment: Please share some sample data and desired results. "I want to collect apples that are red otherwise any other colors except for EA" doesn't make much sense. Are you saying that if the table contains NO records for fruit of "Apple" with a color of "Red" that you want all "Apple" records except color of "EA"? It's not clear with these psuedo-terms.

Comment: To understand how to improve your question, please read this: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Right now this looks as if `SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE fruit = 'apple'` gives you exactly what you want, because apparently the color can be either red or any other color.

Comment: @waka if I only use SELECT * from tableA where fruit = 'apple' it would return all colors if both would be available. I want to specify red apples only. If red is not available then select any other colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what `except for EA` means.

My interpreation is that you want all rows where `fruit = 'apple' and color = 'red'`, but that if there are no such rows, return all the apples *(as none of them are Red)*?

I'd use an `IF` condition to avoid reading the table unnecessarily.

```
SELECT *
  INTO #temp
  FROM your_table
 WHERE fruit = 'apple' AND color = 'red'

IF @@rowcount = 0
  SELECT *
    FROM your_table
   WHERE fruit = 'apple'
ELSE
  SELECT *
    FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Demos : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9ce49d1934c149f787c7317f3186656

Comment: Thanks, the EA was a type and should've been 'red' instead. This is exactly what I was looking for.